# Expected outcome of dice roll modified by a reduction

Tags: probability

```
Compute the damage per second of an attacker with hit probability 50% and 
damage 5d8 against a defender with evasion 10% and block 20.
```

In other words, block is the amount the initial expected value is reduced by and it is asking what is the expected value of 5 8-sided dice with all expected values <=20 gone.

hit chance = hit probability – hit chance reduction
hit chance reduction = hit probability * evasion

in this case hit chance is 45%

For example: 2d6 damage with block 0 is

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 3 4 5 6 7 8
3 4 5 6 7 8 9
4 5 6 7 8 9 10
5 6 7 8 9 10 11
6 7 8 9 10 11 12

add all the values up and divide by 36
```

So I have been working with two dice in a table in order to find basic expected values. This one has me stumped because you would need 5 dimensions to work in in order to do this in a table. The block reduces the amount of possible damage. I'm trying to figure out the expected value overall which should be n/(8^5)

Comment: Can you translate from RPG to English? The only part I understand is "five eight-sided dice"

Comment: +1 to Henry's question. What's DPS? Damage per second?

Comment: yes, DPS is damage per second. pretty much irrelevant in the question I suppose. Just was wondering what the expected value of the 5 8-sided dice - 20 would be.

Comment: And what are evasion and block exactly? Maybe you could transform your question into mathematics (without context) only.

Answer (score 1):

The expected value of $5d8-20$ is $5\cdot 4.5-20=2.5$ if negative results are allowed.  If the roll totals $10$ before the deduction, do you report $-10$ or $0$?.  If you replace all negative results by zero I get an expected value of about $3.54$  I would have expected much higher.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the expected value of sum of $5$ eight sided dice, you can just add the expected value of each of the five dice. Each die has expected value $\frac{1+8}2=\frac 92$. Multiplying by $5$ gives $\frac12 45=22.5$.